# What determines "eligible voters"?

Tags: tropico-6

In the politics tab I can see the information about the support for the next vote. There is also a number for "eligible voters" which is currently 65. However on my island I have a total population of 235 (194 adults).

What makes an inhabitant of my island an "eligible voter"?

Answer (score 2):

In the Constitution Section. The place where you determine the type of rules you will have on your Island. There is a section calling "Voting Rights".

Of your entire pool of citizens, you have 3 ways of determining how people can vote for you.

1. All Citizens Vote
2. Wealthy Citizens Vote
3. Open Ballot Elections

If you had chosen only "wealthy voters" Then only a certain number of citizens would be able to vote from the entire pool of voters on the next election.

After every election, The Constitution can be edited. Or can be edited via "The Broker" section.

[image]